# The difference between "Who did you help?" and "Who helped you?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

QUESTIONS WITHOUT THE QUESTION FORM..  When asking a question in English, we do not always use the question form. However, this is only when a question word, such as “who“, “what“ or “which“, is the subject in the sentence. For example, the sentence **“Who did you help?“** uses the question form
because the subject is the word “you“. However, the question **“Who helped you?“**
doesn’t use the question form because the subject is the word “who“.

Comment: The explanation given seems fairly straightforward. Interrogative pronouns indicate that a question is being asked. The word order in that case is not the normal word order for questions **if** the interrogative pronoun  is the **subject** of the clause. Where is your confusion?

Comment: Both sentence have the same form. They are questions that end in a question mark. So, I don't know what you mean by "question form." Also, in both sentences the subject is *you*, and the object is *who*.

Comment: @JasonBassford: it's clear to me that they mean subject-auxiliary inversion.  Meg: the verb (or auxiliary if required) likes to come second in a sentence or clause. If the question word (which comes at the start) is the subject, then it can be followd by the verb, and there is no need to change. If the subject word is not the question, then the subject and verb are inverted, to keep the verb second; but for verbs other than "be" and for some speakers "have", that means putting the _auxiliary_ "do" before the subject, not the full verb.

Answer (score 0):

We do sometimes ask questions without the question form.   You'll sometimes find a sentence like "You helped John?" instead of "Did you help John?" or "You helped John, did you?"   There isn't even a question word in "You helped John?", but some questions with so-called *wh-* words also lack the question form, like "You helped who?"

Both of your example questions do have the usual question form.   It's just harder to see in the second example because, after moving things around, all the words end up where they started.

> You helped somebody.  Who did you help?

Let's assume we want a question with "who" representing "somebody".  We can go from the statement form of "you helped who" to the question form of "who did you help" in two steps.   We place the first word of the verb in front of the subject, using do-support when we need to.   This gives us the almost-nonsensical "did you help who".   Next, we move the keyword of the question to the beginning of the sentence, giving us "who did you help" -- exactly the question form that you're expecting.

> Somebody helped you.   Who helped you?

Let's make the same assumptions again.   We go from "who helped you" to "did who help you" to "who did help you" -- and we end up with just "who helped you" because the do-support looks like it's doing a different job than simply helping to form the question.   We did all that work and ended up right back where we started.

When the subject of the sentence and the keyword of the question are the same thing, we can skip over all the steps because we know everything will end up back where it started.